# Why this while loop is not breaking?

Tags: c

I am writing a json parser. And while considering such json string `"\"K\":12}]"` for looping I am using a while loop with pointer. The code I am trying is this:

```
while ((*memptr != ',')||(*memptr != '}')||(*memptr != ']'))
            memptr++;
```

When the memptr points to `'1'` of `"12"` it goes on increasing beyond `']'`.
But if the memptr points to `','` or `'}'` or `']'` this loop should break isn't it? but this loop never breaks! And the memptr goes on increasing.
what am I missing?

Comment: [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging logic, make yourself a truth table.

Let the first column be `*memptr`, the second be `*memptr != ','`, then for `}` and `]`, and finally the whole controlling expression `(*memptr != ',')||(*memptr != '}')||(*memptr != ']')`

```
1 | True  | True  | True  | True
, | False | True  | True  | True
} | True  | False | True  | True
] | True  | True  | False | True
```

See the problem?  The controlling expression is always true, so the loop happily continues.

You may choose to instead use a Venn diagram.  Draw three disjoint circles, for `,`, `}`, and `]`.  Now use three different hatching patterns to fill in "things that are not `,`", "things that are not `}`', "things that are not `]`".

What region does the union of these three areas cover?
What region does the intersection cover?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `OR` condition, you have to be very careful on the exit criteria.
Say if your condition is `pointer != A || pointer != B`, 
    When it encounters `A`, the first condition returns false, but second returns true.
    When it encounters `B`, the first condition returns true, so it doesn't evaluate second.

Try using AND.